# Why is the sample space no longer important once a discrete random variable is introduced?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[F.M. Dekking, C. Kraaikamp, H.P. Lopuhaa, L.E. Meester, "*A Modern Introduction to Probability and Statistics*", Page-43.](http://cis-linux1.temple.edu/~latecki/Courses/CIS2033-Spring13/Modern_intro_probability_statistics_Dekking05.pdf)

> Once a discrete random variable X is introduced, the sample space Ω is
>   no longer important. It suffices to list the possible values of X and
>   their corresponding probabilities. This information is contained in
>   the probability mass function of X.

Can you explain this?

Why is the sample space no longer important once a discrete random variable is introduced?

Comment: The sample space is really never important. It is just a framework to let us build random variables, after which we can study them in other ways if we wish.

Answer (score 1):

Given a discrete random variable $\xi$ with values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and corresponding probabilities $\mathsf P\{\xi=x_i\}=p_i$ you can easily build a sample space for it, for example as $\Omega=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $\xi(x_i)=x_i$. So we can exhibit a sample space. Note however that a specific realization of the sample space is irrelevant to everything one wants to do with the random variable.

P. S. Strictly speaking, random variable as a *function* already contain domain in its definition (indeed, in set theory function defined as a special kind of a relation; relation is a tuple of domain $X$, codomain $Y$, and subset of $X\times Y$). But the fact your book mentioned is that for discrete random variable $\xi$ we can "forget" the original domain of $\xi$ and that we can easily build own domain for it. This is why often random variables introduced without explicit definition of its sample space.

Comment: How or where do we obtain $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ if we don't know or need $\Omega$?

Comment: $\{x_i\}$ is the set of possible values of $\xi$

Comment: It should be mentioned, that Corvus' approach easily can be extended from the finite case $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to the discrete (countable) case $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ by taking e.g. $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and setting $\xi(i)=x_i$.

Comment: @anonymous You may obtain the new probability space from the original. *Once you have done so*, you *no longer need* to reference the original when discussing aspects of the random variable.  All the information you need to reference for that has been encoded in the new probability space.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The reason one can forget the domain of a random variable is not because one can build one (and this is not what Dekking and al. are alluding to) but because *the domain of a random variable is irrelevant* to everything one wants to do with the random variable.

Comment: @Did: Thank you! I've edited my answer.